# Progress Bar - gif for php file upload

Tags: php, javascript, upload, gif, progress

I'm trying to realize a page to upload pdf file to my server with php code.
No problem with the upload, but I would like to make something visual for users who should see a kind of progress bar.
Since a real progress bar is a little troublesome, showing an animate gif should be enough.

I've realized a form with an action to load the php file which does the upload, and onsubmit the form calls a function which creates a "layer" with the gif and a message.

```
<form action = "file_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" onSubmit= "Loader()">

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


function Loader (){ 

// Create a white box to cover the page.
var back = document.createElement('div');
back.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
back.style.position = 'fixed';
back.style.zIndex = '0';
back.style.left = '0px';
back.style.top = '0px';
back.style.right = '0px';
back.style.bottom = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(back);

// Add a box to contain the message.
var box = document.createElement('div');
box.style.position = 'absolute';
box.style.zIndex = '1';
box.style.width = '250px';
box.style.margin = '15px ' + ((document.body.offsetWidth / 2) - (250 / 2)) + 'px';
box.style.fontFamily = 'Verdana, Arial, serif';
document.body.appendChild(box);



// Add the "Please wait" header
var message = document.createElement('span');
message.id = 'loading_header';
message.style.display = 'block';
message.style.fontSize = '175%';
message.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
message.style.textAlign = 'center';
message.innerHTML = 'Please wait';
box.appendChild(message);

// Add the subheader message
var message = document.createElement('span');
message.id = 'loading_message';
message.style.display = 'block';
message.style.fontSize = '125%';
message.style.textAlign = 'center';
message.innerHTML = 'Your files are being uploaded.';
box.appendChild(message);

// Add a loading image.
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', './Progress.gif');
img.style.display = 'block';
img.style.width = '64px';
img.style.height = '64px';
img.style.margin = '15px auto';
box.appendChild(img);

}
```

The problem is that the upload works, but no gif is displayed, and a bigger problem is that at home it works, but at work it seems to work anymore.

Do you think it can be an internet connection problem? Any Ideas?

Comment: Is the javascript actually adding these DOM objects? You need to debug that. Try 'FireBug'.

Comment: try http://www.uploadify.com/ - its complete upload widget with multiple files option. There is very nice progressbar solution. uploadify 2 uses flash object to upload files, uploadify 3 uses html5, but its only some alpha yet.

Comment: Try putting the onsubmit as an onclick on the submitbutton perhaps.

Comment: I think that there may be an issue with the img src: 'src', './Progress.gif' I would set a background-image to a div instead of using img src for the gif but don't know about it working in diff locations.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in comments and question edits. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The discussion around the solutions to this question are mainly links to other web sites that have downloadable script solutions to this problem. StackOverflow deprecates answers which are purely URL links, as the link can become stale rendering the answer useless. However the discussion itself is germane to the solution....

@deed02392 wrote:

> Is the javascript actually adding these DOM objects? You need to debug that. Try 'FireBug'.

(N.B: http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug )

@palmic wrote:

> try [uploadify.com](http://www.uploadify.com/) - its complete upload widget with multiple files option. There is very nice progressbar solution. uploadify 2 uses flash object to upload files, uploadify 3 uses html5, but its only some alpha yet.

The OP wrote:

> no way, it doesn't work.. after a lot of attempts I solved with this [www.phpfileuploader.com](http://www.phpfileuploader.com/)